# i want to share image from my android app on facebook, but not upload this image

Tags: java, android, uri, share-intent

**[not upload image to facebook , instagram ect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM9jN.png)**
*hello friends,
why my image not upload anywhere app?*

> share image to facebook and ect

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM9jN.png)

Comment: when you press "this is my code" you will see code

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it can be done that way.

Facebook (or Instagram) would want to have an handle on the image, either by uploading the pic (which seems like you don't want to do) or by pointing to a URL.

To follow through the second option you could either turn the device into an HTTP server (but you'll have issues with battery life or background processes, especially with Android Nougat) or uploading it to a third party hoster (like Google Drive) and then forward that link to Facebook.